# Execute a stored procedure inside textbox to get a localized text

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, localization, ssrs-2008, multilingual

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure inside a textbox? We need this to localize our report.

For example, we have a stored procedure which returns the localized text for a given `Key` and a given `LanguageId`. I want to execute this stored procedure for every Label (Textbox) with a different key inside my report.

We are using SSRS 2008.

Comment: did u define the dataset for that stored procedure yet?

Comment: Yeah I've already defined the dataset for the stored procedure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've got things a little mixed up, you can't *"execute a sproc inside a textbox"*.

What you can do instead, is create a dataset that gets all required Key/Value pairs for your current language, something like this:

```
EXEC usp_GetReportLabels 'en-US'

/* Returns:

   Key       Val
  ---------  ------------
  lbl1       Firstname
  lbl2       Surname
  etc        etc
*/
```

On your textboxes you can use an expression utilizing the [`Lookup` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) to retrieve the correct row from that dataset, and display the label value.

Note: You mention [ssrs-2008](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2008) but not the [ssrs-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2008-r2) edition, I don't think the `Lookup` function is available in plain-2008. In that case you'll need to restructure your dataset(s) a bit to get the same effect. One solution would be to `PIVOT` the dataset and make the `Key`s into columns (the dataset will only contain one row in that case, so you can do `First(Fields!lbl1.Value)`). Bit of a workaround though.

Comment: I extend the stored procedure, so it will return a table with key values and then I use the Lookup Function. Works great! Thx