# How do I run a stored procedure in WinForms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I am using winforms in C# to launch a procedure that is stored in my MS SQL Server database. I only have one variable and it is @XmlStr. I have a text box that is going to include the variable and a button I want to start the procedure. Can anyone help me do this? I have been researching this all day, and so far have come up with nothing that has worked for me.

Comment: Which solutions did you come by that didn't work for you?

Comment: It would help if you told us if and how your stored procedure returns results; output parameters? Selects?

Comment: All the stored procedure does is import the XML to a few SQL tables. The text box is for copying and pasting XML to be inserted into a database.

Comment: I used a number of different sites. Here are a few of the ones I have looked at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918674/execute-a-stored-procedure-inside-textbox-to-get-a-localized-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326946/storedprocedure-in-c-passing-parameters-from-text-boxes http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/329082-how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-winforms/page__st__0%26 http://forums.asp.net/t/716548.aspx?Binding+Stored+Procedure+OUTPUT+parameters+to+a+TextBox+How+

Comment: @Austin how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program

Comment: @Andrey I still do not understand how to do it from that thread.

Comment: @Austin I would recommend you to read a book about development for .net.

Answer (score 5):

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XmlStr", XmlStrVariable);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

This should get you started.  Research SqlConnection and SqlCommand for more information.

[SqlConnection MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SqlCommand MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
string connectionString = "YourConnectionString";
int parameter = 0;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "NameOfYourStoredProcedure";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParameterName", parameter);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Read your reader data
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```